# Would we want to do the work to get advertisements for outdoors on the other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I had thought that ads would have to wait until we get out of beta, but it looks like [Writers](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1464/lets-advertise-writing-on-other-sites-2018-edition) has had them for a while now and they still have a ways to go.

This would not be the actual process of creating the ads as I first wanted to ask if people thought that this is something worth doing as it looks like it will end up being quite a bit of work especially the first time.

Is this something people would be interest in?

See the [post to suggest ads](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/suggest-community-promotion-ads)

Comment: I'd love to be interested but I am not creative in any way shape or form.

Comment: @Liam We basically are going to need everybody we can get, since ads need upvotes to be considered. So just voting will help

Comment: ah OK, cool :) ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be a great idea! I can't think of any downside, except of course the amount of work, and I have absolutely no technical ability to assist with that. It makes sense that you're looking for a consensus among the community before taking that step.

In 2015, Cooking:SE Meta had a [Community Promotion Ads](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/community-promotion-ads-2015) campaign. [Gardening:SE](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/642/what-should-a-community-ad-for-gardening-stackexchange-look-like) created an ad and [submitted it](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/community-promotion-ads-2015/2045#2045) to that campaign. It was subsequently posted on Cooking's [main site](https://cooking.stackexchange.com). I believe other sites, some of which were small or new, ran ads there too.

I don't know how often it ran or for how long. I also don't know how successful it was in driving traffic to the site. I'm sure there are statistics that can be accessed by people who know how to find those things!

I look forward to seeing what other people think about running our own ad.

**NOTE: The rules for size and other things have been changed since that campaign on the Cooking site. I'm leaving the link as an example of what some of the submitted ads looked like at that time. Please see Charlie Brumbaugh's meta post, [Suggesting Community Promotion Ads](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/suggest-community-promotion-ads), for the current instructions and requirements, and a more [relevant link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27800/community-promotion-ads-2018/27895).**

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: Voila - Work is done.

Comment: I really, really like this. The "Forever Beta" joke (well, sort of) might rally support as an "underdog" :)

Comment: Thanks for the work ShemSeger! I love the picture and that the name of the site is clear and bold. I don't think Forever Beta should be there, but I'm not sure if you meant it or not, so I don't want my opinion to be based on something that I hope was just a joke!

Comment: @ShemSeger a version of this without the forever beta bit would be awesome. Then I'd suggest posting it in the Travel.SE ads meta post as well as ours. Let us know when you have so we know to upvote.

Comment: https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/suggest-community-promotion-ads

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]