# Suggest community promotion ads 2018

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

**Update on results:**

- One posted to [Scifi](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11670/community-promotion-ads-2018/11761#11761) -> never got enough votes to work.
- One posted to [Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4630/) -> **1 click since March 6th** maybe because it exceeded the filesize requirements and so was never actually shown to anyone on the site.

TLDR: Instead of bothering with ads, upvote good posts to get them onto the HNQ so we call pull in well over 5,000 views in a week.

**End update:**

Okay, since creating ads is something the community seems to think is worth doing, I am going to start a new question where we can post the suggested ads.

First, here are the [rules](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27800/community-promotion-ads-2018/27895).

**All answers should be in the exact form of:**

```
[![The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange][1]][2]

  [1]: https://image-url
  [2]: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/
```

**Image requirements**

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if
  high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white,
  there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

It will also take 6 upvotes on any of the site metas to get them up and running.

**Now here is the format I would like us to follow.**

- Post the image so that the rest of the community can give feedback and up or down vote them.
- Post the code to make it easy for other users to copy and paste them onto the other site metas to suggest them.
- Once a post is suggested on another site, put the link to that meta post so that members of the community can go upvote it. This will also make it possible for us to keep track of how well the ads did and how well they were received.

Upvotes on ads on this meta won't get it posted, but I would suggest that if users here don't like an ad then the users on the other sites probably won't like it either.

I would also suggest not posting all of the ads to a single meta site.

Comment: Where did you get the image requirements?

Comment: @ShemSeger See any of the other community promotion adds for example https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27800/community-promotion-ads-2018/27895

Comment: You need to get a moderator to ad the magic [tag:community-ads] tag.

Comment: @ShemSeger  not exactly these ads aren’t going on our site but on other full fledged sites

Comment: @ShemSeger see my last three bullet points

Comment: @roryalsop What are the odds we could get the [tag:featured] tag on this?

Comment: Hi Charlie, I've been away for a day or two, so I haven't kept up on the procedure, but I don't see any comments under these suggestions, and your post says we can give feedback. Does that mean we can comment here, and make suggestions as to little tweaks or whatever, or now that they seem to be up and running and seeking votes on other sites, we can't suggest changes here? Thanks!

Comment: @Sue I think you could propose changes either places

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh, that's great, thanks! Also, are we allowed to suggest a site where we might want to see one posted, as long as that site is doing them? Cooking is one I like.

Comment: @Sue I think they are good to go on any site that's doing them. Of course, depending on the community the same ad might fit one site and not another.

Comment: @Sue, I'm in favour of doing tailored ads, like photos of camp cooking to go on Cooking.SE for example.

Answer (score 9):

[image: The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange]

Copy and paste this code to an established site meta such as [Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/community-promotion-ads-2018),[Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27800/community-promotion-ads-2018/27895), [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5801/community-promotion-ads-2018) or [Judaism](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4485/community-promotion-ads-2018) to get it suggested there.

```
[![The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange][1]][2]


   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsApn.png
   [2]: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/
```

Then put a link to the suggested post below so that the rest of the community can go support the ad and we can track how well it does.

Posted at [SciFi](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11670/community-promotion-ads-2018/11761#11761)

Comment: ShemSeger, Would you consider adding an animal or something to one of these pictures? I think birds in the top picture would look pretty and peaceful, maybe something like a v-formation or swarm of birds flying in the sky. They could even look far away, so they wouldn't have to have a lot of definition. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue You probably wouldn't like the pictures I take of birds. I'm pretty sure the last time I shot a photo of a bird it was of an eagle eating a deer.

Comment: I was kind of afraid of that, although of course eagles get hungry too. I'm not sure which sites would love to see that! The last picture of an eagle I saw was a video of a man who found one with frozen wings, took it inside, thawed it out, and sent it on its glorious way to the tops of the nearby trees. It was awesome!!

Comment: If you want, you can use my picture [here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/why-do-some-birds-fly-in-a-v-formation), or at least some part of it.

Comment: This *was* my favourite, but the text "TGO.SE" suggests that it is a URL (which it kinda is [www.tgo.se](http://www.tgo.se/)). I feel loose the TGO.SE totally, it'll also emphasise the speech bubble IMO. I am totally scared to "enter the door of yellow magic" in work hours...

Comment: FYI really, really **brilliant** work :)

Comment: I'm with @Liam. This is definitely my favorite. The photo quality is gorgeous. It's the most colorful, and it really looks like a top to bottom view of the outside world, which is what we're about. I also agree with Liam about the TGO:SE part. If you think it looks empty, you could even just delete the :SE and move the TGO against the bubble. That way we'd have the abbreviation and the spelling, without the risk of looking link-like. We call ourselves TGO anyway, so I think it would fit with our identity.

Comment: Do you want us to delete our comments about birds? I don't think they're necessary but I didn't want to just delete mine and leave yours hanging. Thanks!

Comment: @ Sue I don't see why you'd need to. I'm not opposed to the idea, I just don't have any pictures of birds. We have lots of birds of prey around here, I could probably get some shots of some owls, hawks or eagles. I've just never gone out to take pictures of birds before.

Comment: I have a lot of pics of sunbirds. But nothing that could go well with this amazing work! Also, I agree with @Liam www.tgo.se is a spooky looking site. You might have to edit that text in the ad :D I think that's the only thing that needs to be modified in the pic.

Comment: @Liam You like this second image better?

Comment: I know you were asking @Liam, but I like the second one better!

Comment: Yes shem, really good work

Comment: Now that it has so many votes, can we try this somewhere?

Comment: Rory has tried this on Travel now https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4630/9533

Comment: @ShemSeger I am getting feedback on SciFi that image is bigger then 150KB, can you fix it?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I was unaware that was a delivery requirement.

Comment: @ShemSeger it is listed above in the image requirements.

Answer (score 6):

[image: The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange]

Copy and paste this code to an established site meta such as [Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/community-promotion-ads-2018),[Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27800/community-promotion-ads-2018/27895), [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5801/community-promotion-ads-2018) or [Judaism](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4485/community-promotion-ads-2018) to get it suggested there.

```
[![The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange][1]][2]


    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hig9k.png
    [2]: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/
```

Then put a link to the suggested post below so that the rest of the community can go support the ad and we can track how well it does.

Answer (score 2):

[image: The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange]

Copy and paste this code to an established site meta such as [Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/community-promotion-ads-2018),[Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27800/community-promotion-ads-2018/27895), [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5801/community-promotion-ads-2018) or [Judaism](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4485/community-promotion-ads-2018) to get it suggested there.

```
[![The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange][1]][2]

    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdF0h.png
    [2]: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/
```

Then put a link to the suggested post below so that the rest of the community can go support the ad and we can track how well it does.

- https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4630/74096

Comment: Hi ShemSeger! Thanks for all these options! Would you be willing to try one like this but without the beta symbol? I think it draws the eye away from the  Escape to the Outdoors text, especially with the script font, which I love! It also covers up a large portion of the outdoors! Thanks for the consideration!

Comment: The post on Travel.SE only needs one more upvote.

Comment: And just like that TGO.SE is the ad with the most votes.

Comment: This one hasn't brought in a single click in quite a while, and I have to wonder if it isn't because the filesize is 3 times larger than its supposed to be.

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh File size is such a petty thing to get hung up on. It takes seconds to copy the image into a photo editor and save it out as a smaller size. It's under 150Kb now. Not sure why the Stack Exchange imgur doesn't compress these while processing them on upload.

Answer (score 2):

[image: The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange]

Copy and paste this code to an established site meta such as [Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/community-promotion-ads-2018),[Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27800/community-promotion-ads-2018/27895), [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5801/community-promotion-ads-2018) or [Judaism](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4485/community-promotion-ads-2018) to get it suggested there.

```
[![The Great Outdoors Stack Exchange][1]][2]


    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V8bD.png
    [2]: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/
```

Then put a link to the suggested post below so that the rest of the community can go support the ad and we can track how well it does.